# Problems compiling Python 3.2 and 2.7 using pythonbrew

Tags: python, build, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build multiple versions of python using [Pythonbrew](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew/0.7.3), but I'm getting some test failures.  This is on a VM running: ***Ubuntu 8.04 32bit***

This happens when I use the `--enable-shared` option

The build.log file errors are shown below:

### Python 3.2

Here are the failed tests for Python 3.2:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2: ./python -E -c 'import sys ; from sysconfig import get_platform ; print(get_platform()+"-"+sys.version[0:3])' >platform
find ./Lib -name '*.py[co]' -print | xargs rm -f
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2: ./python -Wd -E -bb  ./Lib/test/regrtest.py -l 
== CPython 3.2 (r32:88445, Jun 16 2011, 15:07:10) [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)]
==   Linux-2.6.18.8-linode22-i686-with-debian-lenny-sid little-endian
==   /opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2/build/test_python_18839
Testing with flags: sys.flags(debug=0, division_warning=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=1, verbose=0, bytes_warning=2, quiet=0)

....SNIP....

[197/349] test_os
test test_os failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2/Lib/test/test_os.py", line 646, in test_exist_ok_existing_directory
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode, exist_ok=True)
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2/Lib/os.py", line 152, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '@test_18839_tmp/dir1'

....SNIP....

321 tests OK.
1 test failed:
    test_os
27 tests skipped:
    test_codecmaps_cn test_codecmaps_hk test_codecmaps_jp
    test_codecmaps_kr test_codecmaps_tw test_curses test_dbm_gnu
    test_dbm_ndbm test_gdb test_ioctl test_kqueue test_ossaudiodev
    test_pep277 test_smtpnet test_socketserver test_sqlite
    test_startfile test_timeout test_tk test_ttk_guionly
    test_unicode_file test_urllib2net test_urllibnet test_winreg
    test_winsound test_xmlrpc_net test_zipfile64
5 skips unexpected on linux2:
    test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_ioctl test_tk test_ttk_guionly
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='a' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

### Python 2.7.1

Here are the failed tests for Python 2.7.1:

```
./python -Wd -3 -E -tt  ./Lib/test/regrtest.py -l 
== CPython 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 17:59:28) [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)]
==   Linux-2.6.18.8-linode22-i686-with-debian-lenny-sid little-endian
==   /opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7.1/build/test_python_19286

....SNIP....

test test_file2k failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7.1/Lib/test/test_file2k.py", line 219, in testStdin
    self.assertRaises(IOError, sys.stdin.seek, -1)
AssertionError: IOError not raised

....SNIP....

343 tests OK.
2 tests failed:
    test_file test_file2k
41 tests skipped:
    test_aepack test_al test_applesingle test_bsddb test_bsddb185
    test_bsddb3 test_cd test_cl test_codecmaps_cn test_codecmaps_hk
    test_codecmaps_jp test_codecmaps_kr test_codecmaps_tw test_curses
    test_dbm test_gdb test_gdbm test_gl test_imgfile test_ioctl
    test_kqueue test_linuxaudiodev test_macos test_macostools
    test_ossaudiodev test_pep277 test_scriptpackages test_smtpnet
    test_socketserver test_sqlite test_startfile test_sunaudiodev
    test_timeout test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_unicode_file
    test_urllib2net test_urllibnet test_winreg test_winsound
    test_zipfile64
8 skips unexpected on linux2:
    test_bsddb test_bsddb3 test_dbm test_gdb test_gdbm test_ioctl
    test_tk test_ttk_guionly
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

### Python 2.7

Here are the failed tests for Python 2.7:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7: ./python -E -c 'import sys ; from sysconfig import get_platform ; print get_platform()+"-"+sys.version[0:3]' >platform
find ./Lib -name '*.py[co]' -print | xargs rm -f
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7: ./python -Wd -3 -E -tt ./Lib/test/regrtest.py -l 
== CPython 2.7 (r27:82500, Jun 16 2011, 15:25:09) [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)]
==   Linux-2.6.18.8-linode22-i686-with-debian-lenny-sid little-endian
==   /opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/build/test_python_13541

....SNIP....

test_distutils
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
test test_distutils failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/tests/test_build_ext.py", line 269, in test_get_outputs
    cmd.run()
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 531, in build_extension
    target_lang=language)
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 741, in link_shared_object
    extra_preargs, extra_postargs, build_temp, target_lang)
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 258, in link
    raise LinkError, msg
LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

....SNIP....

test test_file failed -- multiple errors occurred; run in verbose mode for details
test_file2k
test test_file2k failed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/standingcloud/stack/pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7/Lib/test/test_file2k.py", line 211, in testStdin
    self.assertRaises(IOError, sys.stdin.seek, -1)
AssertionError: IOError not raised

....SNIP....

339 tests OK.
3 tests failed:
    test_distutils test_file test_file2k
1 test altered the execution environment:
    test_site
41 tests skipped:
    test_aepack test_al test_applesingle test_bsddb test_bsddb185
    test_bsddb3 test_cd test_cl test_codecmaps_cn test_codecmaps_hk
    test_codecmaps_jp test_codecmaps_kr test_codecmaps_tw test_curses
    test_dbm test_gdb test_gdbm test_gl test_imgfile test_ioctl
    test_kqueue test_linuxaudiodev test_macos test_macostools
    test_ossaudiodev test_pep277 test_scriptpackages test_smtpnet
    test_socketserver test_sqlite test_startfile test_sunaudiodev
    test_timeout test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_unicode_file
    test_urllib2net test_urllibnet test_winreg test_winsound
    test_zipfile64
8 skips unexpected on linux2:
    test_bsddb test_bsddb3 test_dbm test_gdb test_gdbm test_ioctl
    test_tk test_ttk_guionly
make: [test] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, I manage to get pythonbrew working with 2.7.2 doing the following:

a) First, install all the dependencies needed to compile python.

```
'curl' # not for build, but for steps after
'build-essential',
'libbz2-dev',
'libsqlite3-dev',
'zlib1g-dev',
'libxml2-dev',
'libxslt1-dev',
'libreadline5', # lenny
'libreadline5-dev', # lenny
'libgdbm-dev',
'libgdb-dev',
'libxml2',
'libssl-dev',
'tk-dev',
'libgdbm-dev',
'libexpat1-dev',
'libncursesw5-dev'
```

b) Now install 2.7.2:

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--with-threads --enable-shared" -j2 -v 2.7.2
```

This installs, but is hit by the following [bug](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/issues/43):

> /home/python-deploy/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/bin/python: error
>   while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

*To avoid getting an error after the build when it tries to install setuptools, use the --no-setuptools option, and you might need to use --force on some platforms, as the gdb test fails due to an error in the test itself.

```
pythonbrew install --configure="--with-threads--enable-shared" \
                   --force \
                   --no-setuptools \
                   --jobs=2 \
                   --verbose 2.7.2
```

c) The easiest workaround is to do (with the correct path to your pythonbrew install):

```
pythonbrew use 2.7.2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib
```

or to add it permanently, put the pythonbrew lib path in a file placed under /etc/ld.so.conf.d and the path will be added at startup, or right away running ldconfig:

```
sudo echo /home/user/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/pythonbrew.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

d) Install setuptools or distribute manually, i.e.

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py && easy_install pip
```

And you should be ready to go. Only tested with 2.7.2 on a vagrant debian lenny VM.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a way to make this work without having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I found out that there is an environment variable called `LD_RUN_PATH` that is just like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, except that you set it while *compiling* a program, and it remembers that path whenever it is run (so you don't need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime).

So if you set `LD_RUN_PATH` appropriately while running pythonbrew to install your Python, it should find its own shared library whenever you run it. For example, the following command succeeded for me, including installing distutils and pip, so that module installation is ready to go without any further setup.

```
LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib pythonbrew install -j2 -C '--enable-shared' --force -v 2.7.3
```

Then I can do `pythonbrew use 2.7.3` to activate it and it just works, without setting any environment variables in your shell init or anything.

Of course, you need to know in advance where pythonbrew will install your Python so that you can set `LD_RUN_PATH` correctly. Generally, it would be `$HOME/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-$VERSION/lib`, but if that doesn't work you can always find out by actually installing it once (without `--enable-shared`) and then finding the `lib` directory.

I believe the errors occur because after installation with `--enable-shared`, your installed Python finds the system Python's shared library and uses that, which causes problems if there is any kind of mismatch in the way the two Pythons were built. Using either the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or the LD_RUN_PATH solution forces your Python to use its own shared library.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Thompson's answer is good ... `LD_RUN_PATH` is the proper remedy.

However, rather than hardcoding an absolute path, one can instead use:

`LD_RUN_PATH='$ORIGIN/../lib'`

... where `$ORIGIN` is the `PWD` of the running binary (eg. python).

```
# objdump -x /home/arisinger/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/python|grep RPATH
  RPATH                $ORIGIN/../lib
# ldd .pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/python
    [...]
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /home/arisinger/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f43994f6000)
    [...]
```

... the above will also properly install pip, etc.  Lastly, from `man ld.so`:

```
$ORIGIN and rpath
    ld.so  understands the string $ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN}) in an
    rpath specification (DT_RPATH or DT_RUNPATH) to mean the directory con‐
    taining  the  application  executable.  Thus, an application located in
    somedir/app could be compiled with gcc  -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'  so
    that  it  finds  an  associated shared library in somedir/lib no matter
    where somedir is located in the directory hierarchy.  This  facilitates
    the  creation  of  "turn-key"  applications  that  do  not  need  to be
    installed into special directories, but can instead  be  unpacked  into
    any directory and still find their own shared libraries.
```

**EDIT:** sadly venvs breaks because virtualenv copies the `python` binary (changing `$ORIGIN`), but does *not* copy (or symlink) the library, so C/builtin dynamic modules in the venv end up linking to the system python ... ungood :-( ...

... IMO this is a bug to be fixed (in virtualenv?), but an easy workaround is to manually copy/symlink `libpythonX.Y.so*` into the lib/ dir of the venv ... or do something a little yucky looking like (note X.Y.Z):

`LD_RUN_PATH='$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/../../../../pythons/Python-X.Y.Z/lib'`

... pick whatever is less nasty to you; both verified to work.