# Update python in server running centos/whm?

Tags: python, django, centos, cpanel, yum

I have a server which is running CentOS with cpanel/whm. Otherwise, it is pretty much a standard set up.

My problem is that such server is running python 2.4 and I need python 2.6 or later. How do I upgrade without breaking anything?

By the way, I currently have a django application running on that server, which I would also like to move to python 2.6 without breaking it. Is there anything extra that I have to do to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a **parallel** install of the new Python.

If you try and update the default Python it will break your system completely.

The simplest thing is to [install a newer version using one of the many RPMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465036/install-python-2-6-in-centos) that people have built to solve just this problem.

Whatever you do, **do not** try and install it from source.

Answer (score 1):

I always deploy python applications with [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew), which allows you to easily install and switch between several pythons without having to touch the system python.

Pythonbrew compiles from source, which does require you to have a compiler and the correct libraries & headers installed. You can look at which you need here: [Step by step pythonbrew installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324176/471842) (for debian based systems)

Answer (score 0):

You can install any version of python from source as long as you don't overwrite cPanel's python 2.4 installation at /usr/bin.  To do this, use the -prefix= option when you configure the python 2.x or python 3.x source for build.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to install an alternate version of Python is to download the source and compile it. When you've finished running `./configure` and `make`, you'll want to install using `make altinstall`, with python 2.6 you'd end up with an interpreter named `python26`